# Calling a JavaScript function from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, code-behind

I am calling a JavaScript function from code behind in a button click event handler the issue is that the function executes when the behind code finishes execution, can any one help so that the script function execute at the time I call it ?
regards.

Comment: You will have to supply more code and examples so we can see what's going on there.

Answer (score 2):

Is code behind necessary to create a function dynamically or something like that? If not you could just make your button not call code behind at all:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(event)">Click me</button>
```

and in

```
function myFunction(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

It will prevent button from making a postback. Otherwise if you take out preventDefault() the button would still execute script before executing postback. To execute script from code behind before postback code ends running would require some very evil workarounds using HttpResponse.Flush or something.